# is the standard orientation of the sphere inward-pointing?

Tags: differential-geometry, convention

I realized today that I hold three inconsistent beliefs about the geometry of the "standard round sphere":

1. Its normal is outward-pointing;
2. Its mean curvature (trace of second fundamental form) is positive;
3. Its second fundamental form is the *negative* differential of the normal vector in the tangent directions, $II = -dr^Tdn.$

Am I wrong about one of these conventions?

Comment: What is your choice for the circle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the crux of the issue is how you define normal curvature. You can define it as $\pm II/I$. In [this book](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node29.html#fig:sign_surf_curvat), the authors couldn't decide, and provided two versions of all the important formulae.

My personal choice (and the most common one, I believe) is to define normal curvature as $II/I$, where $II = d\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{dN}$. For the most common parameterisations $(u,v) \mapsto \mathbf{S}(u,v)$ of a sphere, the normal direction $\mathbf{N} = \mathbf{S}^u \times \mathbf{S}^v$ points outwards, away from the center. But then this means that normal curvature and mean curvature are negative everywhere. This is somewhat disturbing, but I've learned to live with it.

Comment: You meant $-dX^TdN$, right?